# How to force data to update when the site is restarted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In Global.asax.cs, I have a List of 5 Cars (The Model, `Cars.cs`, pulls data from the database):

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static List<Car> Cars = Enumerable.Range(1,5)
        .Select(i => new Car(i))
        .ToList();

    protected void Application_Start()...
}
```

Then I use the list on my front page:

```
@foreach(var C in MySite.MvcApplication.Cars)
{
    <a href="/Car_@C.Number">@C.Name</a>
}
```

I  can't figure out how to force the Cars variable to refresh. The quickest way I have found is to log into the server, open IIS, and Stop and Start the website - a simply restarting it doesn't work. Obviously this is not sustainable, and I'm sure there's a better way...

Here's some other things I've tried:

- Created a script that stops the website, waits 5 seconds, and starts it again. This performed the stop and start, but the data did not change.
- Creating an SQL Dependency. This will not work because I use dsn to connect to the database (no way around this).

**I need a way to automate this, so a user can update info and refresh the data without needing me to login to the server every time something changes.**

Comment: why are you getting your `Cars` during the global.asax startup? Shouldn't you get it when a View is called?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I don't want to query the database every time someone visits the front page. The data doesn't change frequently enough for that to be viable. I want to be able to tell it when to reload the data.

Comment: still, the solution isn't to do it during Global startup. You might be best to setup some sort of caching mechanism. Honestly, the calls are not all that expensive to make even if you're doing it once a minute (60 second cache).

Comment: ^ This, or break apart your declaration and assignment and assign it once at app_start and write functionality that lets you call the same assignment logic as needed.

Comment: @moarboilerplate I still don't think ViewModels should be hydrated during `app_start`. It's bad design.

Comment: OK, that's fine if I shouldn't do it in Global startup. The reason it's there is because it was in a Controller before, and I had to push a new dll everytime I wanted the data to refresh. The reason I don't want to use a view is what if it was 500 cars or 5000? This is just a simple version to demonstrate. I'm open to a caching system, how would you do it if you were using a cache?

Comment: @moarboilerplate Can you post an answer that demonstrates what you're saying? I think it's a good idea, but I'm not sure how to pull it off.

Comment: I would but I'm on a plane and my battery's low -_-. In short, just move the assignment from Cars to a method on global and then call that once at app start and then subsequently from your "refresher" page.  @ChaseFlorell View not VM if I'm not mistaken, and this appears to be a one off app considering it has a static dataset. "Good design" might be too heavyweight for such a small bit of functionality. In a sense, this one global dataset dependency being wired up in global accomplishes a primitive "poor man's DI" composition root.

Comment: Got an answer for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the assignment out into a method and call that method once in app start and as needed on your "refresher" page. This will set you up for good DI should you need to start going down that route.

```
public static List<Car> Cars;

public static void GetCars()
{
    Cars = Enumerable.Range(1,5)
    .Select(i => new Car(i))
    .ToList();
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    GetCars();
}
```

Then call `Global.GetCars()` in response to UI events on your page.

Comment: I'm getting a "Response is not available in this context" error on HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(...) in the Car Model.

Comment: OK, changed that to WebUtility, testing now.